# La variable toma el primer dígito que recibe

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo mi proyecto desde hace días y presento varios problemas con el Modal, luego de solucionarlo me surge el siguiente inconveniente.

Estoy pulsando un botón que esta dentro de un foreach para que en una tabla se vaya generando los registros de los usuarios. El problema es que cuando pulso el botón eliminar, aparece el modal y me muestra un nombre y un email, el problema es que ese nombre y ese email es siempre el del primer usuario que aparece en la tabla. Puedo seleccionar otro usuario y el nombre y email que aparece en el modal es el de ese usuario. Aparte que si le doy a eliminar me elimina pero el primer usuario. No el que seleccione.

Aquí dejaré mi codigo **index.blade.php**

```
@section('contenido')
    @include('alertas.mensajeCreado')

    <!--Metodo para hacer la busqueda en los usuarios-->
    {!!Form::open(['route'=>'admin.usuario.index','method'=>'GET', 'class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left pull-right','role'=>'search'])!!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Buscar'])!!}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Buscar</button>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
    <!--FIN DEL METODO-->

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <th class="active">Nombre</th>
            <th class="active">Correo</th>
            <th class="active">Tipo de Usuario</th>
            <th class="active">Operacion</th>
        </thead>
        @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
            <tbody>
                <td class="success">{{$usuario->name}}</td>
                <td class="success">{{$usuario->email}}</td>
                <td class="success">{{$usuario->tipoUsuario}}</td>
                <td class="success">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                        <a href="{{route('admin.usuario.edit', $usuario->id) }}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                        <button href="admin/usuario/destroy" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tbody>
        @include('admin.usuario.destroy')
        @endforeach
    </table>
    <div align="center">
        {!! $usuarios->appends(array('search'=> Input::get('search')))->render() !!}

    </div>

@endsection
```

Y este es el **destroy.blade.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">¿Seguro que desea eliminar?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {!!Form::open(['route'=>['admin.usuario.destroy',$usuario->id],'method'=>'DELETE'])!!}
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token">
            <input type="hidden" id="id">               
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" value="{{ $usuario->name }}" class="form-control" disabled>                  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Email:</label>
                <input type="email" value="{{ $usuario->email }}" class="form-control" disabled>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <center>{!!Form::submit('Si',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])!!}
            <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="return cerrarPopup();">No</a></center>
            {!!Form::close()!!}
            @section('scriptModal')
                {!!Html::script('js/modal.js')!!}
            @endsection
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás referenciando al id del mismo modal siempre, aparte de estar incluyendo un montón de código html innecesario en mi opinión al crear tantas veces el modal.

En todo caso, para que soluciones este problema, puedes pasar la variable del index actual de la colección o agregar un contador si deseas:

```
    @foreach($usuarios as $key => $usuario)
        <tbody>
            <td class="success">{{$usuario->name}}</td>
            <td class="success">{{$usuario->email}}</td>
            <td class="success">{{$usuario->tipoUsuario}}</td>
            <td class="success">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                    <a href="{{route('admin.usuario.edit', $usuario->id) }}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                    <button href="admin/usuario/destroy" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$key}}"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tbody>
    @include('admin.usuario.destroy', ['key' => $key])
    { { ++$key } }
    @endforeach
```

y en la vista destroy:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$key}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
.....
```

El código no está probado, es posible que no funcione 100%, pero es la idea.

Comment: Excelente, perfecto, muchas gracias amigo. Lo único que tuve que hacer fue agregar un codigo php, algo como <?php $key =  $usuario->id; ?> porque así pasaba era el id, si no el key no se aumentaba. Muchas gracias de nuevo Shaz :D